# Common linker to all languages

Tags: linker

Is a linker common to the object codes of various languages for a given ISA? or is it that various languages need separate linker for an underlying platform? I understand linker to be a system software and should be common to all?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that the linker links object code. This object code is machine (and usually operating system) specific. There are several different standard object code formats. A linker can not link object code from different machine architectures. And even if it could do that, it wouldn't execute. That being said, you can almost always link object code from different languages as long as the compilers run on the same machine and sometimes even the same operating system. For example, if you create a program in C and want to link with it a Pascal object file, this will usually work. The most popular object code format is called [COFF object code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF). COFF code is almost universally the accepted standard format for object code. It doesn't matter what language compiler you use to generate the code (as long as its from the same machine architecture), most linkers will understand be able to link COFF files.